# Block every incoming traffic except port 22

Tags: debian, ssh, iptables

Is it a good idea to block every incoming and/or outgoing traffic on my debian 7 vps except for port 22 and/or localhost via iptables? The server doesnt run any applications which are available from the outside.

Update:
Added these two iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: you only us it for `ssh`, do you download any thing from the internet on it ?

Comment: Replacing your final drop all with a "policy" might be more expressive of your intent: `iptables -P INPUT DROP`.

Comment: @DanArmstrong what is the difference and does it affect how the filter works?

Comment: Any traversal of the `INPUT` chain that doesn't terminate will default to the policy.  In more complex setups it can help protect you from yourself by being a default `DROP`.  In effect it'll give the same results in your example, but notice how people use the term "policy", which this more correctly matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safer to use a closed policy: block all ports and open them as you need the service. this will make your machine not vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a good idea.

In my opinion, you need to add anyway some icmp packets.

And I would add a statefull firewall: accept only new connection on 22 and all established connections, so you remove some information gathering about your opened connections, and some attacks about IP flags.

Additionally I would add also a firewall toward outside.